# How extra cookie comes

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, httpcookie

I wrote a program that shows all the headerfield and values of a webpage. I try to match all cookies found from setcookie headerfield with firefox page info.(I add an extension of view cookie) . firefox shows more name value pairs than my own program

here is my code....

```
try
   {
       String line = null;
       URL gmail = new URL("http://www.gmail.com/");
       URLConnection connect = gmail.openConnection();
       Map<String,List<String>>map=null;
       map=connect.getHeaderFields();

        java.util.Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String co = (String)it.next();
            System.out.println(co);
            List<String>word = map.get(co);
            java.util.Iterator ita = word.iterator();
            while(ita.hasNext())
                System.out.println("           "+(String)ita.next());
        }

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
        System.out.println(e);
   }
```

How these extra cookie comes?

Comment: The browser, after loading the initial page, could be running the javascript and making asynchronous requests to the server and that could be setting some more cookies.

Comment: I need these cookies to access the next page . How can I get these cookies?@ Bala R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like HTTPUnit instead of doing the connections yourself.

http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/

Javascript on the page could be connecting to the server, or even to other serves, and getting the cookies from there.